# MySQL query to find customers who have made 0 orders / no orders

Tags: mysql, select, find

I would like to find those customers, who have not made any orders yet.

I have found some queries to find customer wise total no. of orders, but did not able to find/get any query, which returns me those customers ids, which are not into orders table.

Also would like to sort the results by date, like in last month, last year etc.

Any help/idea would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: it help to upload the structure of the tables, sample of query you did ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.CustomerID IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders o WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
```

Comment: Not exist definitely the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.* from Customers c
where c.CustomerID NOT IN (select o.CustomerID from Orders o)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select customer_name from customer               
where customer_id not in (select customer_id from orders);
```